# Is there a simple way to convert JSON file into a Markdown / text table in IntelliJ?

Tags: arrays, json, intellij-idea

Let's assume I have a JSON file that contains an array:

```json
[ {"someField": 335, "someField2": "jkdf}, {"someField": 1, "someField2": "sdf}
```

Is there any plugin / simple way instead of writing own console program, to convert mentioned file into simple text table:

```
|someField  |someField2|
| 335       | jkdf     |
| 1         | sdf      |
```